# Calling JavaScript function after PHP Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why this function isn't being called after the form is submitted.  The "checkForm()" JS function works fine when the form is submitted, but I can't seem to get the checkDates() function working.  I tried moving it above the PHP code and no alert message showed up.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Here's the pseudo code version of my file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['next'])){
    // Some PHP code

    echo "<script> checkDates(); </script>";
}

?>

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php print $thispage;?>" onsubmit="return checkForm()">

// Some HTML code

</form>

<script>
var isDateTimeValid = true;

function checkDates() {
    alert("Hello");
    isDateTimeValid = false;
}

function checkForm () {

    if (isDateTimeValid == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `echo "<script> checkDates(); </script>"` is executing? Can you see the `<script> checkDates(); </script>` part in your HTML source?

Comment: You'll need to put all that after your function definition as well, sense the function must be defined before you call it

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I do not see the "<script> checkDates(); </script>" part in the HTML source, so I don't think it's executing, but not sure why?

Comment: @Phroggyy So, basically put the PHP part under the <script> tags?

Comment: @R.Kelly yep. Although if it's not executing, your issue is a different one. Namely you having the wrong name, `next`, for the submitted field

Comment: @Phroggyy "Next" is right as it's executing other parts of code in that conditional, but just not the javascript.  I tried moving the php to the bottom of the file and it's still not executing.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @R.Kelly what if you echo something else? Does it execute?

Comment: @Phroggyy You were right.  I had to break up the PHP part, so only the 'next' stuff gets executed under the JS code.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this it will work.

here your php code must be last in your file then it will work. otherwise not.

```
     <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return  checkForm()">

     // Some HTML code
     <input type="hidden" name="next" value="sd">
     <input type="submit">

     </form>

     <script>
      var isDateTimeValid = true;

       function checkDates() {
       alert("Hello");
       isDateTimeValid = false;
      }

     console.log(isDateTimeValid);
     function checkForm () {

     if (isDateTimeValid == true) {
        return true;
     }
     else {
        return false;
       }
     }

   </script>
   <?php

    if(isset($_POST['next'])){
      echo "<script> checkDates(); </script>";
     } 
     ?>
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with a brief explanation as to what you have changed in order for it to work?

Comment: when you submit the form the page will refresh so the php code will read the code from top to bottom so it will call JavaScript function which is declare after calling the function so the calling of the function must be in the last. declaration of function must before the calling.

Comment: This worked, thanks!  I believe I need to implement @Swapnil Bhikule's part now to prevent the headers from being sent to the next page.  Not sure who is down voting everyone, but I upvoted all.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks +1 for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should first do this in your javascript function

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
    <!-- some html code -->
</form>

<script>
   // your all code

   $("#form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (isDateTimeValid == true) {
        $.post(
           // post logic with proper url
        );
      }
      else {
        // return some error message
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting the javascript at the top. since you are calling the function which might have not been defined yet in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

the problem was your variable and function scoping all the identifiers must be declared. If you run your code with "browser console output" opened, you will see an "Uncaught ReferenceError: checkDates is not defined" after your form submit. If you put the php code after the javascript function deceleration it will work.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return checkForm()">

// Some HTML code
    <input type="submit" name="next">

</form>

<script>
var isDateTimeValid = true;

function checkDates() {
    alert("Hello");
    isDateTimeValid = false;
}

console.log(isDateTimeValid);

function checkForm () {
    console.log(isDateTimeValid);
    if (isDateTimeValid == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

</script>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['next'])){
    // Some PHP code

    echo "<script> checkDates(); </script>";
}

?>
```

see the browser console output.